# Javascript Prototype adding a observe click on a html tag instead of id or name

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, prototypejs, dom-events

I want to add a observe statement in prototype js on a `<h4>` tag without using any id or name. so for example I have in html:

```
 <h4>Some Item</h4>
```

In Javascript I would like to do:

```
$(<h4>).observe('click', function() {
 //do some stuff here
});
```

I know I can add a id or name on the `<h4>` tag and use that but how do I do it without any id or name tag?

Answer (score 3):

My prototype is rusty but I *think* this will work. Basically it just gets all of the `<h4>`s, loops through them, and adds the event observer.

```
$$('h4').each(function(h) {
  $(h).observe('click', function(e) {
    //do some stuff here
  }
});
```

If you only want the first `<h4>` then using array dereferencing:

```
$$('h4')[0].observe('click', function(e) {
  //do some stuff here
});
```

Naturally if you want the second just change the zero to a one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't. How can the browser distinguish two h4's from eachother with any id?

You can also do

```
<h4 onclick="">
```

but then you can also just give it an id.

Answer (score 1):

[PrototypeJS](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/) has an `invoke()` method that will iterate over the list of items and run the same method on all items in the list.

for example

```
$$('h4').invoke('observe','click',function(e){
    //handle event here
    //'this' is the element
    //'e' is the Event object
});
```